# Scrapy RetryMiddleWare send signal to spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to deliver a message to my spider on retry requests that been issued more than 1 time.

I was thinking to use a signal and to patch the build-in RetryMiddleWare in scrapy to send such signal when conditions are met.

Does it going to work?

How can I trigger a signal in Scrapy?

i did not find any clue on the net.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RetryMiddleware` source is here - take a look at it and subclass it to put needed functionality:

```
scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry.RetryMiddleware
```

Then disable the original and enable the modified one:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'middlewares.MyRetryMiddleware': 500,
}
```

In your customized middleware you can call a spider's method to make an action, or issue a custom signal using dispatcher (i would choose the first method).

Comment: Thanks - call method is the right way to go - i will change it.
I've patched RetryMiddleware for quick and dirty solution but I will take your solution and use my modified one.
do I need to subclass RetryMiddleware and just take the patched function?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "patched". Subclass `RetryMiddleware` and modify `_retry` method (i think). Change its logic to call a specific method of the spider when a certain condition happens.

Comment: ok got it.
general question: lets say I want to ignore a response in parse function - is it enough to return None or should I raise an exception?
I noticed that Scrapy got stuck on such scenarios for couple of seconds.

Comment: A callback can return a `Request`, an `Item` or None. A request will be scheduled for downloading and its callback will be called when it's downloaded. An item will be sent to the pipelines. Otherwise nothing happens.